# Переполнения памяти при шифрование AES больших файлов

Tags: c#, криптография, aes

Столкнулся с проблемой переполнения памяти при шифровании больших файлов.

```
    passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);
    File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytesEncrypted);
    File.Move(file, file + ".crypt");
```

Как переделать шифратор, чтобы была побайтовая запись в файл во избежании переполнений?

Comment: Считываете и шифруйте блоками, например по 1КБ

Comment: если можно пример, я просто не совсем понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего использовать потоки. Ключ и вектор подставите свои:

```
string filename = "123.txt";
using (var fsIn = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var fsOut = new FileStream(filename + ".crypt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
using (var aes = Aes.Create())
using (var enc = aes.CreateEncryptor(new byte[16] /* ключ */, new byte[16] /* вектор */))
using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fsIn, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    cs.CopyTo(fsOut);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Что такое вектор?

Comment: @LeonidPetrovich `IV` или `initialization vector`, для режима шифрования CBC. Если подставите нули (как у меня в примере), тогда получится режим ECB. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: @Zergatul, скажите а какой используется AES в этом примере ? если не присваивается  `aes.KeySize = 256` и `aes.BlockSize = 128`

Comment: @ZidoX подставите ключ 16 байт, будет 128, подставите 32 - будет 256